# Odoo Window action apply multiple filters

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-15

Is it possible to create a window action to automatically apply a filter where origin is either 1 or 2? Something like:

```json
{
            'name': 'Window',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'stock.picking',
            'target': 'current',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'domain': domain,
            'context': {'search_default_origin': ['1','2']
}
```

I'm trying to ultimately add a filter to a view so if a use creates a custom filter, I can replicate it on the next screen.

When I run the above context with the window action, Odoo seems to be searching for origin to contain the literal string 1,2.

I can use a domain but I'd like to use a filter so that the user can remove the filter if they choose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an illustration of how to apply several filters to an action.

```
 return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': _('Taxes'),
            'res_model': 'account.tax',
            'target': 'current',
            'views': [[view_id_list, 'list'], [view_id_form, 'form']],
            'context': {'search_default_sale': True, 'search_default_purchase': True, 'active_test': False},
        }
```